# Auto block contact but unblock it after a couple days

Tags: applications

Is there any way to automatically block a contact after a received call and unblock it again after a given time?

The problem I have is that my mother just can't leave me alone for more than a day. I tried to talk to her about this countless times but she just ignores me and keeps calling. So the idea is to block calls from her automatically after a received call for 2 days and then unblock it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try Root Call Blocker, but your phone has to be rooted. [Root Call Blocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.rootcallblocker.beta) has many options you can set (im not sure if timing of auto block and auto-unblock is available though). Even while the person is calling, there is a swipe button right next to the swipe green button, and you can end the call and block the person then and there.

If your phone is not rooted, then you can use [AFirewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lianyun.afirewall.inapp)

This is also feature rich with options, check to see if there are any auto-block and unblock timers.